# What is the difference between the two different ways of importing Python widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

and:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

I am confused regarding this issue and until further notice I probably include too many imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RealPython has a real nice explanation [here](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#the-import-statement), but to summarize `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *` isn't considered good practice in a large-scale production, as you are importing everything, which could accidentally override other important built-ins, and it may import more than you need. Stick with `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets`

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR; Don't use any of those ways to import

---

Both forms import all the elements of the QtWidgets module so they are considered bad practices.

When Python imports an element then it also imports all the sub-elements it contains, and more elements implies more memory consumption and more load time.

It is recommended to import only the classes, functions, etc. that are going to be used, for example `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`.

<sub>Disclaimer: In many of my answers I use `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` since all my answers are not necessarily intended to provide good practices but to solve a practical problem so I do not distract with extensive imports.</sub>

Comment: Does it make the app slow, importing everything or what is the incitament for not just do that? Could you explain "distract with extensive imports" further? Aha The other answer below explains something. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Biorobot 1) Although the OP's answer links a good post to its answer itself: `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` is incorrect since none of the ways you indicate are a good practice. 2) In my answers that have a code I want users to understand it at first sight and do not have to use the scrollbar so I avoid long imports: from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidgets, ... (another 40 more imports ) since that is not relevant in my SO answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc is right. My point (that looking back I did not express correctly) was that only use what you need.